process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ls, ...) failed. make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified
I have a simple make file:
CC=gcc

output.exe: main.o
    $(CC) main.o -o output.exe

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c main.cpp -o main.o

clean:
    rm *.o

and when i run
make clean

i get the next output and error:
rm *.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ls, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [Makefile:10: clean] Error 2

NOTE! when i run a simple make command:
make
i dont get any error and everything runs smoothly.
whats the deal with the error?

I'm guessing you're on Windows. Do you have a rm command? It's not a default part of the OS so you'd have to install it from somewhere

@AlanBirtles Thanks for the comment. yes, i am on windows, but when i run the command on the Visual Code's terminal it does run without an issue, only when it runs from the make file it fails

Which terminal are you using in vscode? Where did you get make from? Looking closer at the error or looks like it's ls that's missing?

I am genuinely  not sure how to even check that. i would love some help with it.
i installed make using chocolatey

ls works fine

I'd guess you've got a native Windows version of make which has no idea about how to run Linux commands

you are correct, also @HolyBlackCat gave the corretion needed.

rm is not a command that exists on Windows. At least not by default.
I recommend installing MSYS2 and installing Make in it. MSYS2 provides ports of Linux-like utilities, including rm. Using its make will give you access to rm (among other things), which is way easier than trying to write cross-platform makefiles by switching to different commands on Windows.
Alternatively, as a quick fix, use a Windows-specific command (del *.o, I believe?).
